# Insert item in specific index inside the array that is being looped

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the best way to update an array by inserting the new element in specific index when certain condition is met while looping.

```
const exampleArray = [
  {item: 1, count: 5},
  {item: 2, count: 20},
  {item: 3, count: 10},
  {item: 6, count: 9}
  {item: 4, count: 5}]
```

I want to loop the exampleArray while keep track of count and insert new element right after when the count is greater than or equal to 10 and then reset the count to 0 for next loop

so the result I want is

```
const resultArray = [
  {item: 1, count: 5},
  {item: 2, count: 20},
  {item: 'new item 1 as count is over 10', count: 0},
  {item: 3, count: 10},
  {item: 'new item 2 as count is equal to 10', count: 0}, 
  {item: 6, count: 9},
  {item: 4, count: 5}, 
  {item: 'new item 3 as count is > 10, previous two counts (9 + 5 )', count: 0 }]
```

I tried this

```
let count = 0
exampleArray.forEach((item, index) => {
 count += item.count

 if(count >= 10) {
  exampleArray.splice(index + 1, 0, {item: 'item to be added', count: 0}
  count = 0
 }
})
```

Comment: Read the warning under https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#description - this will probably be easiest, if you don't try to mess with the existing array while you are looping over it, but create a new result array instead.

Comment: Where did `{item: 6, count: 9}` appear from?

Answer (score 3):

Both of these create a new array - if you want to overwrite, use let and asssign back to the original

TJ Suggested map and flat - that is a flatMap

```js
const exampleArray = [
  {item: 1, count: 5},
  {item: 2, count: 20},
  {item: 3, count: 10},
  {item: 4, count: 5}];
  
let count = 0;  
const resultArray = exampleArray.flatMap(item => {
  count += item.count; 
  if (count >= 10) {
    count = 0
    return [item, {item:"new", count:0}]
  }  
  return item;
});

console.log(resultArray);
```

Reduce

```js
const exampleArray = [
  {item: 1, count: 5},
  {item: 2, count: 20},
  {item: 3, count: 10},
  {item: 4, count: 5}];
  
let count = 0;
const resultArray = exampleArray.reduce((acc,cur) => {
  count += cur.count; 
  acc.push(cur);
  if (count >= 10) {
    count = 0
    acc.push({item:"new", count:0})
  }  
  return acc;
},[]);

console.log(resultArray);
```

Comment: The OP's modifying the original. This creates a new one.

Comment: const exampleArray ... const resultArray = ...

Comment: Sure -- unless something else also has a reference to it, and that's why they were modifying it in place. Anyway, horses for courses. :-) Hopefully the OP can benefit from both approaches at different times.

Comment: I added a flatMap on your insistance

Comment: ***Gah*!** Why. Do. I. Always. Forget. `flatMap`?!?!?!! :-) It's like a bad sector in my brain.

Comment: Great Answer. Thanks @mplungjan. Never used the flatMap before. Very smart

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for a simple `for` or `for...of` loop. If you're happy to create a new array (if not — I see you aren't in your question — see below):

```
const result = [];
for (const item of exampleArray) {
    count += item.count;
    result.push(item);
    if (count >= 10) {
        result.push({item: 'item to be added', count: 0});
    }
}
```

or *(originally I used `map`...`flat()`, because I forgot **again** about `flatMap`; [mplungjan reminded me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69853868/157247))*:

```
let count = 0;
const result = exampleArray.flatMap(item => {
    count += item.count;
    if (count >= 10) {
        return [item, {item: 'item to be added', count: 0}];
    }
    return item;
});
```

Live Example:

```js
const exampleArray = [
    {item: 1, count: 5},
    {item: 2, count: 20},
    {item: 3, count: 10},
    {item: 4, count: 5}
];
let count = 0;
const result = [];
for (const item of exampleArray) {
    count += item.count;
    result.push(item);
    if (count >= 10) {
        result.push({item: 'item to be added', count: 0});
    }
}
console.log(result);
count = 0;
const result2 = exampleArray.map(item => {
    count += item.count;
    if (count >= 10) {
        return [item, {item: 'item to be added', count: 0}];
    }
    return item;
}).flat();
console.log(result2);
```

If you really want to modify the existing array instead, the `for` loop lets you control the index variable:

```
for (let index = 0; index < exampleArray.length; ++index) {
    const item = exampleArray[index];
    count += item.count;
    if (count >= 10) {
        exampleArray.splice(index + 1, 0, {item: 'item to be added', count: 0});
        count = 0;
        ++index; // Skip the item we just added
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const exampleArray = [
    {item: 1, count: 5},
    {item: 2, count: 20},
    {item: 3, count: 10},
    {item: 4, count: 5}
];
let count = 0;
for (let index = 0; index < exampleArray.length; ++index) {
    const item = exampleArray[index];
    count += item.count;
    if (count >= 10) {
        exampleArray.splice(index + 1, 0, {item: 'item to be added', count: 0});
        count = 0;
        ++index; // Skip the item we just added
    }
}
console.log(exampleArray);
```

Comment: Reduce is so much simpler

Comment: @mplungjan - Strongly disagree, and you're solving a different problem there. If I can just create a new array (the OP modifies it in place), it can be **way** simpler than `reduce`. A simple `for`, a `map` with `flat`, ...

Comment: const exampleArray ... const resultArray = ... did not look like it's in place - his code was but I do not recommend slicing in place

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder, your solution is great too. :)